# pytorch dataset python script does not run in colab

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset

I've decided to make reusable scripts for frequently used classes. So, i made one for my image dataset and imported it in collab. I can create the dataset object successfully but can't get data from it.

here is my dataset code:
https://pastebin.com/XfAiTe3A

Here is how i use the script in google colab:

```
from imageDataset import customDataset
dataset = customDataset(train_data)\
dataset[0]
```

Here is the error:

```
     16         target = self.targets[index]
---> 17         image = io.imread(self.image_paths[index])
     18 
     19         if self.augmentations is not None:

SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
```

But if i copy paste the code in a jupyter cell , i can use the class like i normally  do. What I'm i doing wrong?

any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: use PIL to get the image

Comment: @JamesBarnett no luck dude, I used PIL.Image to read and converted it to numpy array.  I get the same error

Comment: Could you please print data['path'] or if you know what it contains, tell us?

Comment: I don't think the problem because of colab

Comment: @Phoenix you maybe right, but the code works perfectly when i copy paste the exact code in the notebook im working on. And `data` is a pandas dataframe containing image paths and image labels as columns.

Comment: Could you please post the dataframe on your questions?

Comment: I want to see the path whether it is paths to images stored locally or the paths are urls.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to rerun the notebook and the problem fixed itself. Coding truly amazes me

Comment: you should have listened to Moss and Roy, turning it off and on again should've been the first solution.